# How to put endnotes BEFORE citations

Tags: libreoffice

I'm trying to build a simple, mundane scholarly article for publication, which must have text, followed by Endnotes (with a Endnotes heading on a new page), followed by Citations, which must be on a new page. Has anyone actually done this in LO 5+?

I have tried creating a Citation section and a TextandNotes section, with the endnotes at the end of the Text section. This finally sort of worked, except I had to put the Endnotes heading in a page-unique header, and there doesn't appear to be any way to put a page break either at the end of the notes or at the beginning of a section.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I was able to do this by following these instructions:

https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/19550/heading-for-endnotes-page/

The only trick: before highlighting the main body of the report plus notes section heading (as described at the above link), create a page break after the notes section heading and insert an empty section. Then go back and highlight up to the point of (and including) the notes section heading, and proceed as above. This has the result of placing the notes section as desired. I was then able to add references to the following page, using JabRef's referencing add-on to LibreOffice http://jabref.org/), without problems.

I've got a file here that I can share, but not quite sure how to do that... so below is a screenshot.

[image: screenshot of report with notes then references]